# What is "Nusrat"?

Tags: quran, arabic, islamic-basis

In Quran there are ayah which say that Allah gives "Nusrat" to the prophets and muminoons.

What is the meaning of "Nusrat" in Qur'an and Islam?

What is the definition of it?

Comment: There are many verses on this topic please share at least one.

Comment: I'd like to know about all of them

Comment: One meaning I have found out about is "victory". But I'd like to know more details

Comment: First of all the term nusrah نصرة itself doesn't appear in the qur'an at all. But you may find there a whole lot of words of the same root such as the verbs  nasara نصر, istansara استنصر and many relevant nouns and adjectives. If you'd like to have the meaning of all of them the question would be too broad (~88 verses some with two words of this kind). Mainly the meanings however would be somewhere between victory, help and  support for most of them.